# Why are my cookies not being set?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

We're using php to set some cookies for our users based on where they came from - some of these will be set based on the referrer URL, and some will be set based on a short query string in the URL.

We only set 2 cookies, and the purpose is to track where traffic is coming from and include the data in the user's submission for our product - then we are able to track which submissions come from which campaign.

It's a custom wordpress website, so the code is split across a few different files as follows:

header.php:

```
<?php
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $current = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];    
    $bestbefore = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

    if (isset($_COOKIE['ccsvissource']))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if (isset($_GET[gclid]))
        {
            setcookie('ccsvissource', 'Google', $bestbefore);
            setcookie('ccsvismedium', 'Adwords', $bestbefore);
        }
        elseif (stripos($origin, 'facebook') !== false)
        {
            setcookie('ccsvissource', 'Advertising', $bestbefore);
            setcookie('ccsvismedium', 'Facebook', $bestbefore);
        }
        elseif ($_GET[utm_medium] == "111")
        {
            setcookie('ccsvissource', 'Advertising', $bestbefore);
            setcookie('ccsvismedium', 'emailcampaign', $bestbefore);
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie('ccsvissource', $origin, $bestbefore);
            setcookie('ccsvismedium', 'Unknown', $bestbefore);
        }
?>
```

footer.php:

```
<?php 
    $mktSource = $_COOKIE['ccsvissource'];
    $mktMedium = $_COOKIE['ccsvismedium'];
?>

<p class="hide-me" id="mkt-source"><?php echo $mktSource; ?></p>
<p class="hide-me" id="mkt-medium"><?php echo $mktMedium; ?></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var mktSource = $('#mkt-source').text();
        var mktMedium = $('#mkt-medium').text();

        $('#hid-ms').val(mktSource);
        $('#hid-mm').val(mktMedium);
    });
</script>
```

The values will then get passed into the user's application form, with our lead management system doing the rest.

The problem is inconsistency - sometimes the cooks are being set, and sometimes not. Is there a certain circumstance client-side which will prevent cookies from being set?

I understand the user may have cookie tracking switched off, and have accounted for this - the volume of empty cookies is still too high so I think I'm missing something.

Please let me know if you need any further information!

Many thanks.

Comment: If the cookies are used across different subpages (e.g. .../index and .../whatever) you might want to set the path parameter of setcookie to '/' otherwise a cookie that is set in .../index won't be available in .../whatever. That would be `setcookie('ccsvissource', '...', $bestbefore, '/');`

Comment: Thanks @Ch33f, I'll try that and see how I get on.

Comment: definitely, using cookies has many advantages and few critical disadvantages, try find another solution like storing your users data.

Answer (score 0):

With new wordpress i've also face the same problem, my custom cookies wasn't set where my code was correct but somewhere i found that sometimes custom cookies does not work. So finally i found this working example with `wp_head` hook.

Let suppose you want to set 2 different cookies like `Area` and `currency` you need this function with `wp_head`, i have use this in my personal projects. it working prefectly.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_setcookie');
function my_setcookie()
{
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['area'])) {

        $area_set = ($_REQUEST['area']);
        setcookie('area', $area_set, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH);
    }

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['currency'])) {

        $currency_request = ($_REQUEST['currency']);
        setcookie('currency_cookie', $currency_request, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH);
    }

}
```